# Intermittent NSArray indexing exception

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have a crash that happens at least once a day that I really can't seem to put a finger on. It seems to happen to me at random moments and I can't trace the stack to understand why it happens. If anyone can point me in the proper direction or even show me some online documentation and tutorials on how I can properly trace values that would be perfect. The most that I understand is that something is trying to access an index in an array, but I can't figure out for the life of me what that array can be. I've included the information from the output window below:

```
2012-09-28 12:45:26.884 TestApp[1683:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1bdd052 0x19ccd0a 0x1bc9db8 0x29522 0x23e76 0x22bed 0x21e36 0xdfee 0xdba8 0xd3cc 0x1bdee72 0x13339ef 0x1bb197f 0x1b14b73 0x1b14454 0x1b13db4 0x1b13ccb 0x2692879 0x269293e 0xa1ba9b 0x2ded 0x2d25)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) bt
#0  0x98468a6a in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x98554acf in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x9858b4f8 in abort ()
#3  0x021cbe78 in abort_message ()
#4  0x021c989e in default_terminate ()
#5  0x019ccf4b in _objc_terminate ()
#6  0x021c98de in safe_handler_caller ()
#7  0x021c9946 in std::terminate ()
#8  0x021cab3e in __cxa_rethrow ()
#9  0x019cce49 in objc_exception_rethrow ()
#10 0x01b13e10 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x01b13ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x02692879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#13 0x0269293e in GSEventRun ()
#14 0x00a1ba9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#15 0x00002ded in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff39c) at /Users/seb/Desktop/Development/main.m:14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Xcode debugger:

- Tap the Breakpoints button in the toolbar:

[image: Breakpoints button]

- Tap the Breakpoints option in the left pane:

[image]

- Tap the '+' button bottom left, and select 'Add Exception Breakpoint':

[image]

- Tap done in the presented view, and you will see something like this (the top one is disabled):

[image]

- insure your app scheme has lldb enabled:

[image]

Comment: +1 for helping to teach a user how to debug exceptions! Just to add, the problem itself is that something is trying to access the first element of an empty mutable array. Once you find the problem, maybe check to see if the array is empty first before doing whatever you do? Or maybe it shouldn't be empty in the first place and that's the problem?

Comment: I thought of saying something similar to @Metabble, bur really, once you have the line of code that is causing the error, you can then track down the reason (but adding log messages etc). Its a starting point!

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of unnecessary. He shouldn't have too much trouble debugging once he finds where the problem is.

Comment: +1 for teaching me how to fish instead of just bringing me my dinner. Next time I get an exception I can possibly be able to find out what the issue is. Thank you again.

Comment: +1 to you for thanking me! Trust me, I got a lot of help in the past 8 years!